# php jquery ajax append(html) in a loop

Tags: jquery, ajax

Function;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
function detail(dataone) {
      $.ajax({
         url: "detail.php?name=" + dataone,
         cache: false
      }).done(function( html ) {
         $("#detail").append(html);
      }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      });
   }
});
    </script>
```

Loop in a table;

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
 echo "<tr onclick='detail(".$row['column1'].")'>";
  echo '<td scope="row">'.$row['column1'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['column2'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['column3'].'</td>

  </tr>'; }
```

Sample output of loop;

```
<tr onclick="detail(name)">
<td scope="row">name</td>
<td>value</td>
<td>value2</td>
</tr>
```

And html;

```
<div id="detail"></div>
```

I just want to send name to detail.php with get and get back html output to detail div. Why does not this function working? (Nothing happens on tr click, no error)

detail.php

```
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
echo $_GET['name'];  }
else echo "Test";
```

**EDIT**

Changed function with this and it worked.

```
var detail = function(dataone)
{ 
   $.ajax({ url: "detail.php?name=" + dataone, cache: false
   }).done(function( html )
{ 
   $("#detail").append(html);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ }
);
}
```

Comment: What result do you get? Do you get an error?

Comment: @Stasel No, nothing happens on click.

Comment: how does the output look when you call detail.php?name={yourdata}?

you also have no opening table tags, btw. 

how do you call your function detail(dataone)?

Comment: @kraYz `<tr onclick='detail(".$row['column1'].")'>`

Comment: @RidIculous There is table, i just put here while part. Also added detail.php

Comment: maybe onclick="javascript:detail()"

Comment: You put javascript: between " and detail in php code?

Comment: @kraYz Yes. `<tr onclick="javascript:detail(name)">` output does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all, I suggest that you pass the data as an object literal, using the data property in the object used in $.ajax:

```
data: { name: dataone },
dataType: 'html' //since you are fetching HTML
```

And since you probably end up in the error handler right now, you could add one to inspect the error:

```
//...
}).done(function( html ) {
    $("#detail").append(html);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    //handle error
});
```

Which would be equivalent to

```
$.ajax({
//...
error: function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    //handle error
},
//...
```

`thrownError` should probably tell you enough to know what went wrong.

```
$(function(){

    $('.yourTr').click(function(){

          //add ajax stuff here
    });

});
```

Comment: I added .fail to function but still no output. I tried it without data but still not working.

Comment: @milesh Please show me how you trigger the ajax call. Sounds like you don't even end up in the click handler

Comment: @milesh Try adding the click handler using jQuery. Ive posted an example.

Comment: Why isnt calling function with onclick event enough?

Comment: @milesh Look at Jai's code. You are missing some closing brackets etc. That might be the cause. If so, you should be able to see the errors in the debug console (F12)

Comment: Error in console;

`SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

detail(NAME SURNAME) < pointing this "S"

Comment: @milesh Look at what row its located at and add the `)`

Comment: It gives same error at all, with pointing first letter of second word.

Comment: @milesh Multiple arguments should be separated with a comma (name, surname)

Comment: But argument is only one (name surname) that i fetch.

Comment: I made output detail("name surname") and now i am getting detail is not a function error in console.

Comment: @milesh Try handling it in the click event like i posted above

Comment: Working with; `var detail = function(dataone) {
     $.ajax({
         url: "detail.php?name=" + dataone,
         cache: false
      }).done(function( html ) {
         $("#detail").append(html);
      }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      });
} `

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some errors in your function:

```
jQuery(function($){
     function detail(dataone) {
         $.ajax({
               url: "detail.php?name=" + dataone,
               cache: false
          }).done(function( html ) {
              $("#detail").append(html);
          }); //<----------------------------------------this is extra
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
           });
          });
      }; //<-------------------';'
      //<-------------missing the closing doc ready
```

Instead try putting function `detail()` outside of `doc ready` or just `remove the doc ready`:

```
   function detail(dataone) {
      $.ajax({
         url: "detail.php?name=" + dataone,
         cache: false
      }).done(function( html ) {
         $("#detail").append(html);
      }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      });
   }
```

Comment: That happened after edit i think, fixed. Now i have error in console; SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list detail(NAME SURNAME) < pointing this "S"

Comment: `detail(NAME, SURNAME)` this should be `,` seperated.